# Adding/appending a loop to the end of another a loop

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to add a loop to the end of another loop. But all I've tried failed and I don't know what to do

I've tried

```
for i in range(2):
   print i
   for r in range(4, 6):
     print i.append(r)
```

and

```
for i in range(2):
   print i
   print i.append(4,5)
```

I expected:

```
0
1
4
5
```

But I received the following error instead:

Error for the 1st code sample:

```
Traceback:(most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print i.append(r)
AttributeError: 'int object has no attribute 'append'
```

Error for the 2nd code sample:

```
Traceback:(most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print i.append(4, 5)
AttributeError: 'int object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: `range()` gives you a list of integers, and iterating over that gives you each integer. Integers are not lists, so you can't `append` to them. What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: And when you append to a list, the returned value is simply `None`, so nothing would print anyway. `i = list(); for _ in range(2): for r in range(4, 6): i.append(r)`

Comment: Create an empty list at before for loop, then append `i`, then add another separate for loop  for `r` and append r to i using `i.append(r)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code produces the output you seem to require:

```
for i in range(2):
   print i
for r in range(4, 6):
  print r
```

Comment: I think he is requesting a single list for both i and r values

Comment: What makes you say that? The expected output seems clear.

Comment: Only because of the `.append` in his code. I may be mistaken though.

Comment: Ok, I see what you did there. Your answer deserves an up-vote, even though the output is not as requested.

Answer (score 4):

If all you're trying to do is print all values of 2 ranges in succession then just add them together.

```
for i in range(2) + range(4, 6):
   print i
```

Results are as follows:

```
0
1
4
5
```

For Python3 you must either wrap the ranges in `list` or for a more elegant and forward compatible solution use using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) it combines both ranges making them one iterable.

```
for i in chain(range(2), range(4, 6)):
   print(i)
```

If what you're trying to do is make both ranges into a list then chain works as well:

```
list(chain(range(2), range(4, 6)))
#[0, 1, 4, 5]
```

Or just add them together

```
#py2
range(2) + range(4, 6)
#py3
list(range(2)) + list(range(4, 6))
```

Comment: Or just plain `range(2) + range(4, 6)` does the same thing.

Comment: True, I've been using Python3 for way too long.

Comment: For Python3, you could do `list(range(2)) + list(range(4, 6))`

Comment: @FredLarson the `chain()` method is better (more memory efficient) and Python 2's lifetime is almost over

Comment: Yes you could although I do prefer the chain method as the line is more readable and efficient plus allows for more ranges

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Noted. But the question specified Python 2.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Hope the new answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good as well, but if you are expecting a list, this is what you would want to try to do without using imports.

```
lst = []
for i in range(2):
   lst.append(i)
for r in range(4, 6):
   lst.append(r)
print lst
```

Answer (score -1):

your code doesn't work becoz i is a value in the first for loop and you can't append a value to a value.

Below for loops will get your desired result

```
for i in range(2):
   print(i)
for r in range(4, 6):
    print(r)
```